# Dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu 14.04 on an MSI GS63VR machine

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I read a lot of guides on how to dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu (not specifically 14.04) and they all say different things. Some say you need to disable secure boot, others say you can't do that because it will mess everything up. There's also the thing with fast startup. I read that I should disable fast startup when dual booting, else I could lose my data, but I see very few guides mentioning that fast startup should be disabled. If that's such a big problem, why is it not mentioned? Another question that arises: if I have to disable one or both, can I re-enable them after installing ubuntu?
I already resized the partition to allocate some space for ubuntu 14.04, but now I don't know what to do: should I disable secure boot? Should I disable fast startup? Is there a specific way to dual boot windows 10 with, specifically, ubuntu 14.04? Or is it the same with any ubuntu version? Has anyone ever tried to dual boot windows 10 and ubuntu on an msi machine? Is there any issue?
I just want to do this without any problems. I don't want to mess up my computer.
Obs.: My disk is GTP

Comment: @karel No. That was one of the guides I read, and, from what I could understand, OP wants to install ubuntu with windows (wubi or something similar). This is not what I want.

Comment: The OP may have mentioned wubi, but karel's link is a guide for full install of Ubuntu next to Windows.  On fast start up: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation And frankly any guide not mentioning turning Windows fast start up off is worthless.

Comment: What  do you want, a link to a different guide or do you want Ask Ubuntu users to do everything on this page from scratch?

Comment: I simply want to know if i should or not disable secure boot and fast startup. And if I have to disable then, can I re-enable then after ubuntu is installed?

Answer (score 1):

Yea it could happen , but you still can recovery your boot section with running grub from usb with https://www.supergrubdisk.org/ , just burn it from another computer or on another DOK , good luck with the installation.